# how to catch GenServer termination Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a `DynamicSupervisor` with basic settings, I am starting a child GenServer as

```
Supervisor.start_child(Recording.WorkerStarter, %{
  id: String.to_atom(detailed_camera.name),
  camera: detailed_camera,
  sleep: detailed_camera.sleep
})
```

and Terminating it as

```
name
|> Process.whereis()
|> case do
  nil -> :not_found
  pid -> DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child(__MODULE__, pid)
end
```

I want to catch its termination, as when I terminate this child, I want to Log something.

I have tested `terminate/2` in `Recording.WorkerStarter` but it won't get called.

I have tried `handle_info({:DOWN, ref, :process, _, _}, state)` it wont work.

How I can catch `Recording.WorkerStarter` termination?

UPDATE:

this is my worker

```
defmodule Recording.WorkerStarter do
  use GenServer

  require Logger

  def start_link(opts) do
    IO.inspect("Started Recording.WorkerStarter")
    {id, opts} = Map.pop!(opts, :id)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: id)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_fetch_call(state.sleep)
    {:ok, state}
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you return `:stop` from `init/1` callback. The documentation on [`GenServer.terminate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#c:terminate/2) states:

> `terminate/2` is called if a callback (except `init/1`) [...]

That said, you might go through [`GenServer.handle_continue/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#c:handle_continue/2) and return `:stop` from there, *or* trap exists from the calling process with [`Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Process.html#flag/2).

Comment: I just saw your PR on elixir repo and I knew you will be answering here as well :D

Comment: but i didnt understand the answer at all.

Comment: I updated the worker code, can you tell where this terminate will fit?

Comment: Make the supervisor of `Recording.WorkerStarter` trapping exits with `Process.flag(:trap_exit)` and you’ll receive `:DOWN` message there, _and_ `terminate/2` will be called.